# validate and compare email in inputbox

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Am trying to validate email address and also if the entered email address  match's the one we don't want.

the button should remain disabled until everything is fine. and re-enable

But when i try to enter valid email or email which is not equal to test@test.com
the button remains disabled

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.keyup-email').keyup(function() {
    var inputVal = $(this).val();
    var emailReg = /^(?!.*_)\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})/;
    if(!emailReg.test(inputVal)) {
      $(".edBtn").prop("disabled", true);
    }
    else if(inputVal == 'test@test.com') {
      $(".edBtn").prop("disabled", true);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="keyup-email text-input" name="7" value="">
<div class="row">
  <button type="button" id="m1p" class="edBtn">submit</b></button>
```

Comment: *"the button remains disabled"* - Where in your code do you ever re-enable the button?  In your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77245855/compering-entered-email-in-inputbox) (now deleted) you had code that worked as intended and enabled the button accordingly.  Why did you remove that?

Comment: @David am just trying. thats why i came here seeking for help, i dont know much. just learning

Comment: @David that deleted question wasn't doing what i need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add else to your conditional statements and make the button disabled to false.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
                $('.keyup-email').keyup(function() {
                    var inputVal = $(this).val();
                    var emailReg = /^(?!.*_)\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})/;
                    if(!emailReg.test(inputVal)) {
                        $(".edBtn").prop("disabled", true);
                    }
                    else if(inputVal == 'test@test.com') {
                        $(".edBtn").prop("disabled", true);
                    }else{
                        $(".edBtn").prop("disabled", false);
                    }
                });
            });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
   
    
 


<input type="text" class="keyup-email text-input" name="7" value="">
<div class="row">
                                            
    <button type="button" id="m1p" class="edBtn">
        
            submit
        </b>
    </button>
    
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

> the button remains disabled

Because you never enable it.  Currently your code has two conditions under which you disable the button.  Do you want it to be enabled otherwise?  Then add that condition:

```
if(!emailReg.test(inputVal)) {
  $(".edBtn").prop("disabled", true);
}
else if(inputVal == 'test@test.com') {
  $(".edBtn").prop("disabled", true);
}
else {
  $(".edBtn").prop("disabled", false);
}
```

Basically, if you want the button to be *not be disabled*, set the `disabled` property to `false`.